# Polymorphic Comments Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to display polymorphic comments on both Album and Photos pages. Will give Album page example below.

This is the **NoMethodError** I receive when I go the Album's index page: 
[image]

How do I fix it?

Current setup information is provided below.

Please let me know if further information is needed. Thank you

**Current Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160916091714) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  end

  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "album_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.index ["album_id"], name: "index_photos_on_album_id", using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "photos", "albums"
end
```

**Current Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root to: 'albums#index'

    resources :albums do 
        resources :photos 
    end

    resources :albums, :photos do 
        resources :comments 
    end

end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def new 
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new
    end

    def create 
        @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)

        if @comment.save 
            redirect_to :back, notice: 'Your comment was successfully posted!'
        else 
            redirect_to :back, notice: "Your comment wasn't posted!"
        end
    end

    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end

  def find_commentable
     @commentable = Album.find_by_id(params[:album_id]) if params[:album_id]
     @commentable = Photo.find_by_id(params[:photo_id]) if params[:photo_id]
  end

end
```

**Current Album Index Page**

```
<h1>All Albums</h1>

<%= link_to 'New', new_album_path %>

<p><%= notice %></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>

    <% @albums.each do |p| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= p.title %></td>
        <td><%= p.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Rename Album', edit_album_path(p) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'See Album', album_path(p) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', album_path(p),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>



<h3>Comments</h3>

<%= render @album.comments %>

<ul>
  <%= render 'comments/form' %>
</ul>
```

**Current _comment.html.erb in Comments View folder**

```
<h1>Comments</h1>

<div id="comments">
  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class="comment">
      <%= comment.content %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**Current _form.html.erb in Comments View folder**

```
<h1>New Comment</h1>

<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2>Please correct the following errors.</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 8 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the singular `@album` on a index view that displays `albums` in plural.

If you wanted to display the comments for each album you would need to iterate through `@albums`.

```
<% @albums.each do |a| %>
  <%= render a.comments %>
<% end %>
```

If you want all the comments that are for albums you would do something like:

```
<aside>
  <h2>Recent comments</h2>
  <% Comment.where(commentable_type: 'Album').limit(10).order(created_at: :desc).each |c| %>
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>
</aside>
```

Your doing the exact same misstake as above when it comes to the form.

Think of your partials as functions that take arguments and return a chunk of html. So lets start by refactoring `/views/comments/_form.html.erb` to use locals instead of instance variables:

```
<%= form_for([commentable, comment ||= commentable.comments.new) do |f| %>
  <% # ... %>
<% end %>
```

`comment ||= commentable.comments.new` is a nifty trick using conditional assignment that lets you use the same form for new/create and edit/update without explicitly passing `comment: album.comment.new`.

You can then render the form from within a loop:

```
<% @albums.each do |a| %>
  <h2><%= a.title %></h2>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/form', commentable: a %>
<% end %>
```

Or from [a partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```
# albums/index.html.erb
<%= render @albums %>

# albums/_album.html.erb
<article>
  <h2><%= album.title %></h2>
  <%= render partial: 'comments/form', commentable: album %>
</article>
```

Comment: ok, so, instead of `<%= render @album.comments %>`, I put your first code block, ie `<% @albums.each do |a| %> ... `, and I got this message: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` in reference to the first line `<%= form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>` in `_comment.html.form` as posted above ... how do I resolve this?

Comment: You should start by learning about the difference between instance and [local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables).

Comment: um ... I do know the difference between the two ... clearly i'm missing something in my post ... please let me know?

Comment: Edited - you are making the same misstake as above - basically you are using ivars in a way that works if you are dealing with a single record but not on a index.